# rooted spatial query with sub-select in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am trying to put together a query to find nodes that are within 2km of a node in my graph.  Say I have a dataset that marks some geoglyphs from the nazca lines:

```
Name,Latitude,Longitude
Hummingbird,-14.692131,-75.148892
Monkey,-14.706940,-75.138532
Condor,-14.697444,-75.126208
Spider,-14.694145,-75.122381
Spiral,-14.688277,-75.122746
Hands,-14.694459,-75.113881
Tree,-14.693898,-75.114520
Astronaut,-14.745222,-75.079755
Dog,-14.706401,-75.130788
Wing,-14.680309,-75.100385
Parrot,-14.689463,-75.107498
```

I have a spatial index created using:

```
CREATE INDEX GeoGlyph.index.Location 
ON GeoGlyph(Latitude,Longitude) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE
```

Now, I want to find the nodes within 2km of the "Hands" glyph, I can enter in this query by manually putting in the Lat/Long coordinates:

```
SELECT Name, Latitude, Longitude, $distance AS Distance 
FROM GeoGlyph 
WHERE [Latitude,Longitude,$spatial] 
NEAR [-14.694459,-75.113884,{"maxDistance":2}] 
ORDER BY Distance
```

I get the result:

```
+----+------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|#   |Name  |Latitude  |Longitude |Distance            |
+----+------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|0   |Hands |-14.694459|-75.113884|5.230883384236603E-6|   
|1   |Tree  |-14.693897|-75.11446 |0.08836486627516459 |
|2   |Spider|-14.694363|-75.12358 |1.0442063409276094  |
|3   |Spiral|-14.688309|-75.12276 |1.1754176535538237  |
|4   |Condor|-14.698346|-75.128334|1.6149944044266815  |
+----+------+----------+----------+--------------------+
```

So far, so good.

Since it's a bit of a pain to type in the coordinates, I'd much rather just look for glyphs within 2km using the Name field "Hands".

This is where I'm currently stuck. I think I should be able to use [LET block](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/SQL-Query.html#let-block) to get what I want... but what I've tried so far isn't working:

```
SELECT *,$distance AS Distance 
FROM GeoGlyph 
LET $temp = (SELECT * FROM GeoGlyph WHERE Name = "Hands")
WHERE [Latitude,Longitude,$spatial] 
NEAR [$temp.Latitude, $temp.Longitude,{"maxDistance":2}] 
ORDER BY Distance
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the way to do it... if it's safe to assume that the field `GeoGlyph.Name` is unique, I can use `first()` in the NEAR clause:

```
SELECT *,$distance AS Distance 
FROM GeoGlyph 
LET $temp = (SELECT * FROM GeoGlyph WHERE Name = "Hands")
WHERE [Latitude,Longitude,$spatial] 
NEAR [first($temp).Latitude, first($temp).Longitude,{"maxDistance":2}] 
ORDER BY Distance
```

This seemed to do the trick.

```
orientdb {db=nazca.orientdb}> SELECT *,$distance AS Distance FROM GeoGlyph LET $temp = (SELECT * FROM GeoGlyph WHERE Name = "Hands") WHERE [Latitude,Longitude,$spatial] NEAR [first($temp).Latitude, first($temp).Longitude,{"maxDistance":2}] ORDER BY Distance

+----+-----+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS  |Latitude  |Longitude |Name  |Distance           |
+----+-----+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------+
|0   |#25:5|GeoGlyph|-14.694459|-75.113884|Hands |0.0                |
|1   |#25:6|GeoGlyph|-14.693897|-75.11446 |Tree  |0.08836394983673491|
|2   |#25:3|GeoGlyph|-14.694363|-75.12358 |Spider|1.0442092937404572 |
|3   |#25:4|GeoGlyph|-14.688309|-75.12276 |Spiral|1.1754175925032648 |
|4   |#25:2|GeoGlyph|-14.698346|-75.128334|Condor|1.614998440581846  |
+----+-----+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------+
```

I'm still not sure exactly how I'd do this if I couldn't rely on uniqueness of the `Name` field though.  For example if I wanted to compute all the pairs of geoglyphs within 2km of each other...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the use of the first() function. I was struggling with something pretty similar to your question, and it seems that your approach may solve it See. [http://stackoverflow.com/q/43861961/5013735](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43861961/5013735) Time to try it!

Comment: @jobel Hi, my understanding here is that the trick with LET $temp = (SELECT ...) actually has $temp storing a list of results.  My example keys off knowing that $temp will only have 1 entry in it since the Name field is unique, I can use first() to just pull the first entry out of that list and reference its elements.