# OrientDB spatial query to find all pairs within X km of each other

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm testing out the [orientdb spatial module](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Spatial-Index.html).  I've put together a simple dataset with coordinates for a few of geoglyphs in the nazca lines (`nazca_lines.csv`):

```
Name,Latitude,Longitude
Hummingbird,-14.692131,-75.148892
Monkey,-14.706940,-75.138532
Condor,-14.697444,-75.126208
Spider,-14.694145,-75.122381
Spiral,-14.688277,-75.122746
Hands,-14.694459,-75.113881
Tree,-14.693898,-75.114520
Astronaut,-14.745222,-75.079755
Dog,-14.706401,-75.130788
Wing,-14.680309,-75.100385
Parrot,-14.689463,-75.107498
```

I create a spatial index using:

```
CREATE INDEX GeoGlyph.index.Location 
ON GeoGlyph(Latitude,Longitude) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE
```

I can generate a list of nodes that are within, say 2km, of a specific geoglyph using a query like the one I generated in [this stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942434/spatial-query-with-sub-select):

```
SELECT $temp.Name AS SourceName, Name AS TargetName, $distance.format("%.4f") AS Distance 
FROM GeoGlyph 
LET $temp = first((SELECT * FROM GeoGlyph WHERE Name = "Tree"))
WHERE [Latitude,Longitude,$spatial] 
NEAR [$temp.Latitude, $temp.Longitude,{"maxDistance":2}] 
ORDER BY Distance
```

which gives me this result:

```
+----+----------+----------+--------+
|#   |SourceName|TargetName|Distance|
+----+----------+----------+--------+
|0   |Tree      |Tree      |0.0000  |
|1   |Tree      |Hands     |0.0884  |
|2   |Tree      |Spider    |0.9831  |
|3   |Tree      |Spiral    |1.0883  |
|4   |Tree      |Condor    |1.5735  |
+----+----------+----------+--------+
```

This is nice, but I can only find the nodes relative to a specific node.  I would like to expand this to ask for all pairs of nodes that are within 2km of each other.

A result that I'm interested in would look something like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
|#   |SourceName |TargetName |Distance|
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
|1   |Hummingbird|Monkey     |1.6314  |
|2   |Monkey     |Dog        |1.8035  |
|3   |Dog        |Condor     |0.9349  |  
|4   |Dog        |Spider     |1.5487  |
|5   |Condor     |Spider     |0.6772  |
|6   |Condor     |Spiral     |1.2685  |
|7   |Condor     |Tree       |1.5735  |
|8   |Condor     |Hands      |1.6150  |
|9   |Spider     |Spiral     |0.6797  |
 ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the new spatial module feature with OPoint type

and use  ST_Distance_Sphere function

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Spatial-Index.html#stdistancesphere-from-orientdb-224

Comment: Thanks, I can look into that. I'm not using the WKT method because our data isn't using WKT.  Perhaps in the future.  This still doesn't really help my primary question: currently the only way I'm getting this working is with a rooted search for nodes with 2km of a specific node.  I want to find _all pairs_ of nodes that are within 2km of each other. I can do it in javascript or Java easily enough, but I'm looking for a query-based solution.