# How to make a ST_spatial query ST_Within Orientdb by selecting spatial classes

Tags: lucene, orientdb, orientdb2.2, pyorient

I am trying to understand how to use the LUCENE Spatial queries in Orientdb 2.2.17 using pyorient.

I have note yet figure it out how to select all the properties of a point vertex class that is within a polygon vertex from another class.[image: This is a visual representation of the problem, where the labels represent the station_names.]

Region Vertex Class has two properties:

1. name
2. coordinates  (EMBEDDED OPolygon) LUCENE index

   `CREATE CLASS Region EXTENDS V`

   `CREATE PROPERTY Region.name IF NOT EXISTS STRING`

   `CREATE PROPERTY Region.coordinates IF NOT EXISTS EMBEDDED OPolygon`

   `CREATE INDEX Region.coordinates ON Region(coordinates) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE`

Points vertex class, also with two properties:

1. station_name
2. coordinates (EMBEDDED OPoint) LUCENE index

   `CREATE CLASS Point EXTENDS V`

   `CREATE PROPERTY Point.station_name IF NOT EXISTS STRING`

   `CREATE PROPERTY Point.coordinates IF NOT EXISTS EMBEDDED OPoint`

   `CREATE INDEX Point.coordinates ON Point(coordinates) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE`

Now, addding region polygon points:

```
INSERT INTO Region SET name = 'region01', coordinates = St_GeomFromText("POLYGON ((13.178784796476098 59.058001210852922,14.161006039084404 59.058001210852922,14.176596852459138 58.122552408368826,13.178784796476098 58.122552408368826,13.178784796476098 59.058001210852922))")
```

Adding the Points vertex:

```
INSERT INTO Point SET station_name = 0, coordinates = st_GeomFromText("POINT (13.459419437221328 58.808548196857167)")
INSERT INTO Point SET station_name = 1, coordinates = st_GeomFromText("POINT (14.332504986206489 58.605867622985606)")
INSERT INTO Point SET station_name = 2, coordinates = st_GeomFromText("POINT (13.724463264591824 57.779554514124655)")
INSERT INTO Point SET station_name = 3, coordinates = st_GeomFromText("POINT (12.617515514985637 58.66823087648455)")
```

I tried with something like and its variations but failed, here is the query example:

`SELECT from Point WHERE ST_WITHIN(coordinates, ST_AsText(SELECT coordinates FROM Region where name='region01')) = true`

I got the following error, I have tried different ways on the query without success.

> Error parsing query: SELECT from Point WHERE ST_WITHIN(coordinates,
>   ST_AsText(SELECT coordinates FROM Region where name='region01')) =
>   true ^ Encountered "" at line 1, column 25. Was expecting one of: DB
>   name="envlay-db"

The expected result is to retrieve the point with station_name=0 that is contained by the polygon.

Any help would be most appreciated.

;)

Jobel

Comment: Can you post the error and some sample data with expected result?

Comment: Dear Roberto, I have extended the example with the code to replicate the example, and output error.